# Enviar un punto en una peticion get en una web api con c# y angular

Tags: c#, angular, get, webapi

Estoy validando un email asincrónicamente con Angular, contra una WebApi

```
validate(control: AbstractControl):  Observable<ValidationErrors> {
  const valor=control.value;
  const campo="Email";
   return this._http.get<Usuario>(`${this.api_url}/api/Usuario/porcampo/${campo}/${valor}`, {headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}});     
 }
```

El problema es que al enviar un . en el valor, ya que el mail es por ejemplo algo@asad.com
La la ruta a la api no es encontrada, solo me pasa con . ? etc. osea, si el mail es algo@asad, llega al controller perfectamente.

En c# el método en el controller es así:

```
[System.Web.Http.Authorize(Roles = "UsuarioAdmin)]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        [System.Web.Http.Route("porcampo/{campo}/{valor}")]
        public IList<L_Usuario> BuscarPorCampo(string campo,string valor)
        {
                Usuario ob = new Usuario();
            IList<Usuario> a = ob.BuscarPorCampo( campo,valor);
            return a;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo resolví de la siguiente forma, en angular llamo pasando el valor en la url luego del signo ?

```
 return this._http.get<any>(`${this.api_url}/api/Usuario/porcampo/${campo}/?valor=${valor}`, {headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}})
```

y en la web api uso fromUri para tomar el valor de la url

```
 [System.Web.Http.Route("porcampo/{campo}/{*valor}")]
        public IList<L_Usuario> BuscarPorCampo(string campo, [FromUri] string  valor)
        {
                Usuario ob = new Usuario();
            IList<Usuario> a = ob.BuscarPorCampo( campo,valor);
            return a;
        }
```